# Andrew Wilson remains an enigma

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, immigration, ireland

I am trying to find the parentage and immigration for Andrew Wilson my 2nd great grandfather. According to family search he was born on August 1, 1838 in Gulladuff, Maghera Parish in Londonderry Ireland.

He married Elizabeth H. Jennings on June 22, 1861 in Queenstown, Armstrong County, Pennsylvania. Elizabeth was born in Gwinear, Cornwall, England and immigrated here in 1850 as a child.

Andrew was a Civil War Veteran and enlisted on August 15, 1863 in the state of New Jersey. He enlisted in Company A, 12th Infantry Regiment on August 20, 1863.

The first census I have him in is the 1870 census in Queenstown, Armstrong County, Pennsylvania. His occupation was a Cooper and he was living with his wife, three children and a woman, Annie Wilson age 78. I am assuming this is Andrew's mother. Annie does not appear in the next census, so I would assume she had passed away by then. Again, I am assuming she is buried in Pennsylvania but have been unsuccessful in verify her death or burial site.

Ultimately, Andrew, his wife and children left Pennsylvania and moved to Olean in Cattaraugus County, New York. Andrew died on January 26, 1899 in Olean NY. I have obtained a copy of his obituary but it did not reference his parents.

I believe Andrew came to the states as a child but have not been successful in finding any immigration or naturalization records and have come to a standstill in trying to locate his immigration to the US or who his parents were (other than the reference to Annie Wilson in the census).

If any one has any suggestions or ideas on pointing me in a direction that I may have missed in trying to track Andrew down it would be appreciated. Thank you i advance for any assistance or suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to GFH! _Thank you_ for such a complete question!

Comment: @user633 "According to family search he was born ..." What am I doing wrong? Using the FamilySeach "search" feature, I have not been able to locate a historical record reporting  about an Andrew Wilson born August 1, 1838 in Gulladuff, Maghera Parish in Londonderry Ireland. Perhaps you could point me somehow to the record. TY

Comment: GeneJ, It is not historical. It is in user submitted genealogies submitted by a family member. I used the death date for Andrew that this person submitted to obtain his obit.

Answer (score 5):

Which port of entry is the most likely?

Answer:

The port of Philadelphia in the state of Pennsylvania, is probable.

Example:

Name:                   Andrew Wilson

Arrival Date:           6 Aug 1851

Age:                    15 Years

Estimated Birth Year:   abt 1836

Gender:             Male

Port of Departure:  Londonderry, Ireland

Ship Name:          Competitor

Port of Arrival:    Philadelphia, Pennsylvania

Microfilm Roll Number:  M425_73

[image]

In the 1860 US Census Andrew Wilson would have been around 22 years old. That said he was either married, single, a boarder, or lived with his parents or other relatives.

That being said I'll presume that Andrew was single until he married, as mentioned in your question. So, let's see what we can find.

Example:

```
 1860 United States Federal Census Record for Andrew Wilson
```

Name:   Andrew Wilson

Age in 1860:    23

Birth Year: abt 1837

Birthplace: Ireland

Home in 1860:   Cowanshannock, Armstrong, Pennsylvania

Gender:     Male

Post Office:    Rural Village

Household Members:

Name            Age

John Wilson 70

Martha Wilson   50

Daniel Wilson   25

Andrew Wilson   23

Nancy Wilson    20

John Wilson 15

[image]

You state in your question "1870 census in Queenstown, Armstrong County, Pennsylvania. His occupation was a Cooper.

Definition:
coop·er
/ˈko͞opər/

Noun- a maker or repairer of casks and barrels.

Verb- make or repair (a cask or barrel).

Synonyms- hooper

Further along in your question you state, " and he was living with his wife, three children and a woman, Annie Wilson age 78. I am assuming this is Andrew's mother. Annie does not appear in the next census, so I would assume she had passed away by then. Again, I am assuming she is buried in Pennsylvania but have been unsuccessful in verify her death or burial site."

There was one result that likely fits on (findagrave.com)

Name: Annie Wilson

Birth:  Jan. 9, 1794

Death:  Apr. 21, 1871

Burial: Lancaster Cemetery, Lancaster, Lancaster County, Pennsylvania, USA (Plot: 556)

[image]

With the records I've provided, you should be able to compare your records and discern if any of the names in the 1860 Federal Census record above coincide with your 1870 Federal Census co-resident "Annie Wilson". It's hard to match dates exactly, the only thing that any of us can do is find sources of evidence and evaluate it's credibility, happy hunting and good luck. : }

Comment: Thank you for the assistance Ezri. I do have the this passenger list in my shoe box on ancestry.

Comment: Looked promising; your welcome, I'll add to the answer when I get some time this weekend. : }

Comment: A probate record about the father (as per the census) might report the names of surviving heirs; it might report about their locations. Ala, it might help you develop the genealogical proof that your ancestor is one and the same, his son. Ditto; John Wilson owned land (per the census), so the deeds may provide the same insight.

Comment: Good observation GeneJ

Comment: Unfortunately, I have eliminated the Andrew Wilson listed in the 1860 census in Cowanshannock as this appears to be a different Andrew. This Andrew shows up in an 1870 census with his mother, Martha and my Andrew is in Queenstown, married with three children.

Comment: I will look into the Annie Wilson buried in Lancaster as this is a potential lead for her. I just received the last of Andrew's children's obits. Andrew had 7 children total. 6 lived to adulthood. Based on three of the children's obits, they were moving between Warren, Venango and Armstrong county PA. I am assuming he was moving the family for work. He was making barrels for oil storage. Then they moved into Olean NY which had a large oil industry also.

Comment: During that time period, oil production (kerosene..etc.) was documented quite nicely "Rockefeller" surname and Railroad contracts may give you a migratory pattern.

Comment: I don't believe I would eliminate these records from my research, as a Genealogical study we only eliminate with strong evidence, with what I see here I would not say without a doubt that Annie Wilson is the Mother. Remember that people lived as a family unit. All relatives: cousins, aunt's, Grandmothers... etc. There is a large gap in the age of Annie and Andrew,  Annie is very likely not Andrews Mother. Annie would have had to been about 46 years old at the time of Andrews birth.

Comment: @user633  I am from Ireland and checked the records at this site http://derry.rootsireland.ie/.  There was an Andrew Wilson born in Derry in 1838 but not in Maghera.  You need to pay a token fee to view this record and it may be worth checking this out.  Also have you checked Scottish records.  I suggest this as this area in Ireland has strong Scottish links.  Andrew is a common Scottish name

Comment: Thank you Stephen Myall. I will check out the website above and start looking at Scottish records. You may be right as growing up we were always told we were of Scottish decent. Irish was never mentioned.